# SharePoint 2013 App with Workflow and custom Task List

Tags: 2013, workflow, task-list, app

In my current project, I want to create a Workflow within a SharePoint App.

This Workflow uses a History and a Task List. But I don't want to generate these Lists. 
I want to create my own custom List and select it as the Task List for the Workflow.

How is this possible? 
All my Lists arent listed in the creation routine of the Workflow. And afterwards I can't select them, too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the Template (ID) of your List in both Element.xml to "171".

But I got an error, related to my workflow, which I'm not sure if its caused by this change.

I will try to find out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add columns to the task form that are populated during the workflow? If so, then what you really want is a custom Content Type that inherits from Workflow Task.

The wizard that is invoked using Add New Item in Visual Studio template will prompt you for the lists to use for Tasks/History. Included in the drop down is  . When this choice is selected, the project will have List Instances added that utilize the correct List Template type (140 for History, 171 for Tasks).